# How to Scraping JS pages with Splash?

Tags: python, scrapy, splash-screen

I'm traying scrape this link but I do not succeed it and I do not get any mistakes, my values are going blank.

I'm using python scrapy and splash. What's wrong ? Anybody help me ?

This my spider code :

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
  import scrapy
  from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
  from boom.items import BoomItem
  from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


  class OrumcekSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'orumcek'
        start_urls = ['example.com']

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
      yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, endpoint='render.html')

def parse(self, response):
        item = BoomItem()
        item["BrandName"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='data-item']/div/a/span/text()").extract()
        item["BrandSector"] = response.xpath("//*[@id='data-item']/div[3]/span/text()").extract()

        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `data-item` but it's not `id`, in image i show you how you can copy **selector** or **xpath**

[image]

Rendering of this page takes time, you should wait till you find your element that you want.

```
  while not splash:select('.your-element') do
    splash:wait(0.1)
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer., I'm going to try the method you said.

Comment: @EmreAydınsoy when you use splash or selenium for rendering, you should put delay because rendering it takes time

Comment: I did not see anything like this in scrapy or splash documents, thank you.

Comment: @parik `time.sleep()` won't help, though, you need to either call [`splash:wait`](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html?highlight=wait#splash-wait) in Splash LUA script or pass `wait` in `args` parameter to `SplashRequest` if you want to wait to page being rendered.

Comment: @TomášLinhart Yes you are right, thanks, i edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to find any element with `id` equal to `data-item` on the page, neither in page source nor while inspecting it. However, there are elements having *attribute* `data-item`. So there probably is not a problem with rendering using Splash, you just have to modify your XPath to something like

```
item["..."] = response.xpath("//*[@data-item]/...")
```

Comment: No, but I got a new perspective ^^